# Cloud SQL Postgres TypeOrm config issue

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, nestjs, typeorm, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Nest.js deployed Google cloud app engine and Cloud SQL postgres typeorm

Here is my config file

```
{
"type":"postgres",
"extra":{"socketPath":"/cloudsql/xxx:us-central1:xxx"},
"username":"xxx",
"password":"xxx",
"database":"xxx",
"synchronize":false,"logging":false,
"entities":["dist/**/*.entity{ .ts,.js}"],
"migrations":["/workspace/dist/src/db/migrations/*.js"],
"migrationsTableName":"migrations_typeorm",
"migrationsRun":false,
"cli":{"migrationsDir":"src/db/migrations"}
}
```

But app engine ignores socketPath and automatically use DEFAULT host and port 127.0.0.1:5432

What is wrong with my config options?

Comment: Did you see this - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#node.js

Comment: Have you checked on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211252/trouble-connecting-node-js-app-to-cloud-sql-database)?

Answer (score 0):

When running the project locally, everything is okay but when deployed to the cloud it's not working. The reason is that locally you don't need "host" property but cloud server needs "host" property which should be the same socketPath ("/cloudsql/xxx:us-central1:xxx").

So when you are on localhost then remove "host" property.
When deploying to server attach "host" property.